# How can I make and upload a torrent file?

Tags: bittorrent

How can I make and upload a torrent file?

Comment: superuser is for computer hardware and software related questions **only**. This is considered **off topic** as defined by the site scope laid out in the [FAQ](http://superuser.com/faq).

Comment: You're probably best not asking here, this is like asking "How do I create a Word document." Better to visit one of the [torrent help](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&client=firefox-a&hs=XT4&rls=org.mozilla%3Aen-US%3Aofficial&q=torrent+help&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=) pages.

Comment: I don't see why this should be off-topic, the only problem I see is that @Rounak should try and formulate what he tried himself, before asking such a 'basic' task when wanting to torrent a file.

Answer (score 6):

uTorrent has a detailed explanation including every detail you should know to create and upload a torrent:

[**How to Make a Torrent**](http://www.utorrent.com/documentation/make-a-torrent)

I'd like to point out the things you must consider beforehand:

> ### Things to consider before making a torrent
>
> - Before you make a torrent, it would be wise to pick a site and review its
>     policies and rules, which can be found
>     in their FAQ section.
> - Your site of choice may have restrictions about content; some do
>     not allow porn, some specialize in
>     specific type of content (such as
>     music, or anime).
> - Your site of choice may also have some specific requirements about
>     content and demand that you add some
>     extras to your torrent such as
>     signature files and ads.
> - Some public sites require registration for uploading; all
>     private sites do.
> - It is important to consider the size of your content for two reasons:
>     first, not everyone has sufficient
>     disk space for very large torrents;
>     and second, larger torrents require
>     longer seeding times. In such cases
>     consider making multiple torrents
>     based on some practical partition such
>     as years, season, parts.
> - Before making your torrent, select your content's location carefully as
>     it will have to remain there (during
>     initial seeding at least).
> - The files in your content must not be modified after you have made the
>     torrent, as this would cause
>     corruption in the torrent.
> - Make sure the files are not in use while you make the torrent.
> - There is no need to compress multiple files into one archive. Many
>     torrenters find it annoying. It also
>     requires twice the space: once for the
>     original and once for the archive.
> - You may wish to make a torrent for exclusive distribution among friends
>     and family. In such case, you may
>     choose to distribute your torrent in
>     some other manner.

Answer (score 0):

[TorrentFreak: How to create a Torrent](http://torrentfreak.com/how-to-create-a-torrent/) explains this in detail.

If you want to put your torrent online, go to the website and look for a place to upload the .torrent.

Answer (score 0):

1. First click on File. (in BitTorrent).
2. Click on Create New Torrent.
3. If you want to add a file, click on Add file and add the file you want. 
   Clicking on add file will attach a single file.
4. If You want to attach a folder, click on Add Directory.
5. Note down the Trackers. You may need it.
6. Click on Create and save as...

A torrent file will be saved. Open it and it will be uploaded.